# c# WCF maximum string content length quota

Tags: c#, wcf

I know this has been posted a few times but I am starting to pull my hair out...  I am getting the following error:

The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'CreateEmailEntry'. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 157, position 92.

Here is the endpoint configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAddEmail" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/AutoSearchEmail/AddEmail.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAddEmail"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IAddEmail" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAddEmail" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Here is the configuration for the WCF project:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAddEmail" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I have read so many posts which say "Increase the maxStringContentLength" which I believe I have but its most probably something I have overlooked...

I really don't like the idea of creating the endpoint in code - just sounds like an extra layer of something else to go wrong!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did u tried with  maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"

Comment: Just added with the same result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the service configuration, is this your whole  configuration, because I´m missing the

```
 <services>
```

section where you apply the binding to your service.

Comment: Bang on - I did use the WCF Service Configuration Editor to make my life easier.  Thank you!